# Stop macro to allow the workbook to be edited

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to open a workbook and filter data by the number in a particular column. I need to filter "0" first and then edit the data and then filter between "+8" and "-8".

I added a message box to pause the macro but I am not able to edit the opened workbook while the message box is displayed. I tried with "Application.waiting" option.

I need to pause the macro automatically and start it manually.

```
Sub Filter_data()

Workbooks.open"D:\Reposrts\AAA.csv"
Activesheet.Range("I1:I100").Autofilter field:=1,Criterial:="0"
Activesheet.columns("A:Z").Autofit
MsgBox"Task ok"       'Here I need to pause the macro and allow for edit opened wb and then manually start macro for below line'
Activesheet.Range("I1:I100").Autofilter field:=1,Criterial:=">8", Opersator:=xlAnd, Criterial:="<-8"

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe split the macro into two macros? And have the second macro run after the user's manual actions? You could have the macros assigned to buttons or keyboard shortcut -- for user friendliness/convenience if that's a concern.

Comment: As I am new to VBA writing,my knowledge is not that much of vast about excel macro.How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to start the macro manually by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Split your existing Macro into two parts

   - The first part contains everything up to have the `MsgBox"Task ok"` line
   - The second part contains everything *after* that point
2. Create a **Modeless** (or "Non-Modal") User Form with your label and an "OK" button to call the second part of your split macro

   - "Modeless" means you can edit the workbook while the User Form is open.  `MsgBox` is "Modal", which is why you can't edit anything.  More details [available from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/modal-and-modeless-dialog-boxes)
3. Replace the `MsgBox"Task ok"` line in the first part of your split macro with a line that opens your User Form.

Once the first half-macro has finished, and the User Form is waiting for you to click "OK", you will be able to edit workbooks.  Once you click "OK", the second part will start.

It is **probably** best to first consider if the "edits" you need the user to make are possible via VBA, a User Form, or a DialogBox (which include the likes of the "Select Range" DialogBox, or the "Colour Picker" DialogBox)

Comment: When I click the link you have shared "available from Microsoft" it displays me C++ language.Is "Modeless" option is available for VBA?

Comment: @NilushaMadumal Yes - "Modal" and "Modeless" is a fairly generic term, available in C, VB, Java, JavaScript, Python, etc.  It's basically programmer talk for "does this window/popup/code stop you doing anything else until it's closed/finished?"

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you not to try to edit the Workbook while a macro is running- I don't even think that is possible at all. Furthermore, try not to refer to ranges by activating/selecting ranges.

```
Activesheet.Range("I1:I100").Autofilter 'Instead of this use the code below

With Workbooks("AAA.csv")
.Sheets("NAME").Range("I1:I100).Autofilter
'More code
End With
```

Like Chillin mentioned, you could assign hotkeys to your filter macros- split them in two. Other than that, you can use buttons to activate the macros.

To assign a keyboard shortcut to a macro:
Press ALT+F8 to open the macro dialog box. Select the macro, and click on Options. In the window that opens you can assign a keyboard shortcut to the macro you selected.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to edit a workbook while a macro is running - just include the line `Stop` as a code-level breakpoint, then hit F5 or the "resume" button in VBA when you're done, like debugging.  It tends to be fairly situational (e.g. when you need a user to select a range of cells), and can **usually** be replaced with a UserForm or DialogBox.  There *are* a limited number of actions that the user can perform in Excel that aren't available via VBA though, such as "recolour picture" (The `PictureFormat.Recolor` method is not available in Excel)

Comment: As someone who's writing VBA programs for users who should have absolutely zero access to the code, having them open the VBA window to continue the code sounds ludacris to me. I suppose it is possible, but that seems a far beyond favourable solution.

Comment: Agreed - that's why in the rare situations it **is** required I would recommend the "Modeless User Form" method.  (`Stop` and Breakpoints don't work when the Project is Protected either)  But it can be done, for crude rapid prototypes/testing purposes

Comment: There are a lot to learn from you @Chronocidal and TIm Stack.I would really appreciate for allocating your valuable time to solve my matter.It seems to me that assign a keyboard shortcut is a better method to pause the macro and allow for editing.